# Composer inside docker complains about a PHP version I am not using

Tags: php, laravel, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Trying to do a Docker setup since I need to run an older version of a Laravel project  for work

This is my Dockerfile

```
FROM php:7.2-fpm-alpine

WORKDIR /var/www/html

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql
```

This is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

networks:
  laravel:

services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:stable-alpine
    container_name: nginx
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html
      - ./nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    depends_on:
      - php
      - mysql
    networks:
      - laravel

  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7.22
    container_name: mysql
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: homestead
      MYSQL_USER: homestead
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: secret
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
      SERVICE_NAME: mysql
    networks:
      - laravel

  php:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: php
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    networks:
      - laravel

  composer:
    image: composer:latest
    container_name: composer
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    depends_on:
      - php
    networks:
      - laravel

  npm:
    image: node:13.7
    container_name: npm
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    entrypoint: ['npm']

  artisan:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: artisan
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    entrypoint: ['/var/www/html/artisan']
    networks:
      - laravel
```

For some reason when I try to do docker-compose run --rm composer update it complains about my version being 8.2.1 despite 7.2 being specified.

When I run

```
docker-compose run --rm composer update
```

This is what I am getting

```
  Problem 1
    - phpunit/phpunit[6.0.0, ..., 6.5.14] require php ^7.0 -> your php version (8.2.10) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - Root composer.json requires phpunit/phpunit ~6.0 -> satisfiable by phpunit/phpunit[6.0.0, ..., 6.5.14]
```

But when I run

```
docker-compose run php --version
```

This is what I am getting

```
PHP 7.2.34 (fpm-fcgi) (built: Dec 17 2020 10:32:58)
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technolog
```

ies

Comment: It seems like you have a couple of things declared as long-running "services" that just try to run developer tools.  How is a long-running Composer or NPM container used, or do these containers just exit immediately?  (Should you be running Composer in your PHP application's Dockerfile instead?)

Answer (score 1):

`image: composer:latest` is not the same image you are building with your Dockerfile and has a different PHP version.

This is not a recommended way to run composer according to [the official docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/composer) hub page:

> Our image is aimed at quickly running Composer without the need for having a PHP runtime installed on your host. You should not rely on the PHP version in our container. We do not provide a Composer image for each supported PHP version because we do not want to encourage using Composer as a base image or a production image.

What is recommended is to change your dockerfile to:

```
FROM php:7.2-fpm-alpine

WORKDIR /var/www/html

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql

COPY --from=composer /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer
```

Then your composer image would be:

```
 composer:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: composer
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    depends_on:
      - php
    networks:
      - laravel
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    entrypoint: [ '/usr/bin/composer' ]
```